# Ajax not able to post base64 string to node js server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to post data (base64 string) to server. when I JSON.stringify the data on console log. I am getting blank output and i am not able to send the data to server.
my ajax code is

```js
base64String=[{data:"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ....."}](long string)
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:3000/",
          type: "PUT",
          data: JSON.stringify(base64String),
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown)
          }
        });
```

Comment: Missing `"` in line 3

Comment: that is typo mistake while typing question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

a string isn't json. Yu would need to do somethng like:

`{ string: <base64> }`